# fullScreenSourceRect not working in Adobe Air Android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, fullscreen

Simplest possible example, a new .fla, targeting AIR 3.8 for android, stage sized 1600x900, with the following AS3 on the first frame:

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
import flash.display.Shape;

var rect:Shape = new Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,640,480);
addChild(rect);

stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
```

I would expect the device to 'zoom' to show only the green rectangle - that's how the *exact same code* works when compiled for windows rather than android - but instead, I just get the normal view of the stage, with the rectangle up in the corner.

what am I missing?

Comment: Weird thought...what if you swap the last two lines? Totally theorizing here.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html)

> The fullScreenSourceRect property can only be set when Flash Player or AIR is not in full-screen mode. To use this property correctly, set this property first, then set the displayState property to full-screen mode.

Are you setting FULL_SCREEN first as in your example?